# firefox extension, jquery and accessing the document

Tags: jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I can easily traverse the current window while I'm inside the pageLoad function in my extension using content.document, but when I try accessing it in another function, called with setInterval, I can't access the content.document.

I tried content.document, document.defaultView, window.content.document and basically every other sensible combination I could think of.

please help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by getting the document object out of an event like so:

```
   e.target.defaultView.document
```

The event object is available in any event listener function - for e.g. you may be capturing the document loaded event by doing something like this:

```
   var appcontent = window.document.getElementById('appcontent');
   appcontent.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onPageLoad, false);
```

In this example, the onPageLoad function gets an event argument that can be used to fetch the document.

To be able to access the document object elsewhere, set a global variable pointing to that. And if using jQuery, pass this as the optional second argument to the $ function (i.e. the context on which jQuery works).

Comment: Are you greasemonkey's author by chance? I was just reading the code to that plugin and that's exactly how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that wouldn't' work (I'd have to see more code).  However, an alternative would be to use `gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument`.