# Firefox extension, accessing the document

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am having trouble accessing the document in my firefox extension. I am trying to get `*target*.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", Run.writeToFile(line.value), false);` to work, however I keep getting errors no matter what I try for my target. I have very little understanding of all of this and have pretty much tried everything I could find on the internet.

This seems to work for evaluating xpaths:

```
    var doc = top.document.getElementById("content").selectedBrowser.contentDocument;
    var item = doc.evaluate(
                            treeView.model[i].xpath, 
                            doc, 
                            null, 
                            XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, 
                            null);
```

`doc.location.href` works for changing the URL.

So I tried using doc.addEventListener...

Here is the error I get. `[Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://spextract/content/scripts/run.js :: anonymous :: line 35"  data: no]`

I also tried these -> [firefox extension, jquery and accessing the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027889/firefox-extension-jquery-and-accessing-the-document)

All help is very much appreciated. And let me know if any more info would help.

**Edit:** Also, if anyone knows how to get it to work with window.onload, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get my document using this:

```
var doc=window.content.document

if(doc != null) {
var data = doc.getElementById("detail")
    ....
}
```

Notice that this is only visible from the Extension scope.